# Modelling common incentives and strategic manipulation

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, industrial-organisation, bayesian-game

There are many situations in the markets when small or larger portions of traders collude and make a strategy manipulation through communication, even they have heterogeneous endowments and information, only because they have common goals (incentives).

Does anyone know any paper, or has any evidence, in literature about common incentives modelling and manipulation strategies?

Comment: Doesn't this cover pretty much every form of collusion?